# How Do I Count Unique Values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The data below is a small extract of my dataset. I have been trying to work with a formula to get a count of the unique number of times a day of the week appears for a room in given date range.

[image: Data Table]

Here is the formula I tried to use:

```
=FILTER(Table1,Table1[Exam Rm Number]=I2)*(Table1[Day of Wk]=I1)
```

Here is the result I am getting:

[image: Results]

Can anyone help me with a formula to return what I am looking to do?

Comment: Do you want to get a **count** of the unique values or a **table** with the unique values?

Comment: So check out functions like countif() or countifs() and unique()

Comment: I want to get a count on unique values as I am going to use that in another calculation.

Comment: @Solar Mike - I have but I couldn't figure out how to get the number of Unique Thursdays Room 1 was used in the given date range.

Comment: The show what you have used, that way we can suggest improvements instead of just functions.

Comment: @Solar Mike - here is the formula that I used =FILTER(Table1,Table1[Exam Rm Number]=I2)*(Table1[Day of Wk]=I1) You can see the dataset and the result in the images in my post. Thanks,

Comment: @RobParkerMBACMPECPXP Sir, could you try this formula, it would return `2` for `Room 1` `=LET(
       a,Table1[ApptDate],
       b,Table1[Day of Wk],
       c,Table1[Exam Rm Number],
       d,HSTACK(a,b,c),
       ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(d,(b="Thursday")*(c="Room 1")))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, then you would need to use a formula like as below:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B12`

```
=LET(
     a,Table1[ApptDate],
     b,Table1[Day of Wk],
     c,Table1[Exam Rm Number],
     d,HSTACK(a,b,c),
     ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(d,(b="Thursday")*(c="Room 1")))))
```

---